# Windows XP page file on laptop second SSD drive

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, ssd, pagefile

I saw a question on moving hyberfile.sys to a different drive from the boot partition, which I was considering as I have an SSD as the second drive in one of my laptops. All the answers say you can't - ok - but I *can* move the page file to the SSD drive. So now I'm considering that.

My questions are these:

1) Has anyone moved their page file to a second SSD laptop drive and experienced a perf boost when paging occurs (even with 3GB of accessibl memory, I can still quite easily cause paging by using VPCs, SQL Server, IE, Word, PowerPoint etc)
2) Has anyone hit any problems doing this?

I already know how to do it, so I don't need information on that.

I'm expecting the answers to be that it works just fine and there aren't problems - but before doing it I'd like (even anecdotal) confirmation from someone who's done it.

Thanks!

PS Not that it should make any difference, but it's XP SP3 on a Lenovo T60p with a 7200rpm main drive and a 128GB SSD second drive, dual core with 4GB ram (3GB accessible).

Answer (score 1):

There are the normal issues of having a paging file on an SSD, mainly the limited number of writes (erases, whatever) an SSD supports.

I have never done it, but, with the fact that XP is not always best with SSDs, you may get at most a small performance boost. Roughly the same type of performance boost as if you moved the page file to any drive besides the boot drive.

Answer (score 1):

My roommate saw a significant speed boost when he changed a flash drive into a ReadyBoost drive, but that doesn't work for XP, only Vista and Win7.

I expect you'd get the normal speed boost from moving from HDD to SSD, plus a small boost because it'd be on a different drive and wouldn't interfere with other operations. I'd say do it. Having put my Windows partition on a separate drive from all my apps, I can say that splitting the OS from the apps does make a difference in terms of latency.